# How do mobile apps share details with each other to show customized ads

Tags: information-gathering, mobile-app, information-exposure

My question is more towards how this is implemented. I mean do they expose apis to each other or store data at a common place to be accessed by others. Please excuse me if it seems too naive.

Comment: ad networks and cookies that are shared between apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The apps do not share information. They use an ad network to display ads to users. Many apps will use the same networks, and those networks are also used by websites, so the ***network*** knows the user's behaviours on the apps and the websites that use them. That way the ***network*** shows relevant ads to users.

The apps and websites don't actually know what ads are being shown to users.